# How templates streaming works in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, streaming, lazy-evaluation

In the Rails API documentation, here what is said about streaming templates.

> **When to use streaming**
>
> Streaming may be considered to be overkill for lightweight actions
>   like new or edit. The real benefit of streaming is on expensive
>   actions that, for example, do a lot of queries on the database.
>
> In such actions, you want to delay queries execution as much as you
>   can. For example, imagine the following dashboard action:
>
> ```
> def dashboard
>   @posts = Post.all
>   @pages = Page.all
>   @articles = Article.all
> end
> ```
>
> Most of the queries here are happening in the controller. In order to
>   benefit from streaming you would want to rewrite it as:
>
> ```
> def dashboard
>   # Allow lazy execution of the queries
>   @posts = Post.all
>   @pages = Page.all
>   @articles = Article.all
>   render stream: true
> end
> ```
>
> Notice that :stream only works with templates. Rendering :json or :xml with :stream won't work.

The thing that I do not understand is, how does using `stream: true` option, will make the queries go through a lazy execution? The queries here are called before the render method, so how all this works?

Answer (score 0):

Those queries will already be lazy by default, regardless of `render stream: true`. That's just how `Model.all` works. It isn't until you call a method that triggers the query to actually run (e.g. `inspect` when you run this code in the rails console). See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f0d3c920a5aeb3babc35500e13288e148238b65e/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L24-30.

Also, for what it's worth, I believe streamed template rendering is opt-in in rails 3, but the default in rails 4.